# Auto-Grant my Approval to a Release if I'm the one that iniated that Deployment

Tags: azure-devops

I have Approval checks set up for my DB layer releases.
They're great for gating anything that was triggered automatically, or that another team member has proposed.

But if *I'm* the one that initiated the Deployment, then it feels somewhat unnecessary for me to also click through the Approve dialog.

Obviously if there are other Approvals required then they should be honoured, but I'd like my approval to be implicit from the fact that I deliberately clicked a button saying "deploy this specific Release".

**Is there any way to configure ADO to behave like this?**

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: Sorry :) Yes (in the sense that I don't need to keep looking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such setting in a release pipeline. Currently, there are following Approval policies only:

[image]

You could submit a user voice at website below:

https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=suggestion&space=21